# Flutter: I can't get rid of the overflow

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to align two DropdownButtonFormField on one line on a Model S phone, but there's a 25px overflow on the second DropdownButtonFormField that I can't get rid of.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppStyle.backgroundColorGreen,
      body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _key,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 30),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: (Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                              maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth * 0.4),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 11, color: AppStyle.colorGrey),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.filter_alt,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(19, 119, 0, 100),
                                ),
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 15, horizontal: 8),
                                isCollapsed: true,
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                              ),
                              iconSize: 0,
                              hint: const Text("Filtrer par :"),
                              isExpanded: false,
                              value: plantFilter,
                              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  plantFilter = newValue;
                                });
                              },
                              items: <String>[
                                'Roses',
                                'Tulipes',
                                'Lys',
                                'Orchidées'
                              ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value,
                                  child: Text(value),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                    Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                              maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth * 0.6),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 11, color: AppStyle.colorGrey),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    vertical: 15, horizontal: 8),
                                isCollapsed: true,
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey, width: 0.3),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                ),
                              ),
                              hint: const Text("Filtrer par :"),
                              isExpanded: false,
                              value: postFilter,
                              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  postFilter = newValue;
                                });
                              },
                              items: <String>[
                                'Voir tous les postes',
                                'Voir les postes gardés',
                                'Voir les postes non gardés'
                              ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: value,
                                  child: Text(value),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
```

In the beginning, there was no Flexible widgets, there were only SizedBoxes with which I set finite widths, and it worked, but the rendering in responsive was disgusting. So I added a LayoutBuilder with Flexibles, but the second DropdownButton still overflows by 25 pixels. I've played around with the constraints maxWidth a bit, but to no avail. I tried replacing Flexible with Expanded, but both DropdownButtons end up the same size so that's not what I want. I also tried replacing my SingleChildScrollView with a ListView with shrinkWrap set to true, but no success aswell. Do you have any ideas ?

I think the answer should be obvious for a flutter expert, but since I'm new to this language and I don't find it intuitive, I'm struggling a bit lol.

Also, if you have any tips on how I could optimize this code in any way, I welcome them. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do a small change, i tried in my system

in 2nd dropdown make isExpanded = true,

```
hint: const Text("Filtrer par :"),
isExpanded: false,   // make this true
value: postFilter,
```